# Prolog - checking if element is a member of a binary tree

Tags: prolog

How do you check if an element is in a binary tree? For example,

```
tree1(node(10,empty, node(100,empty, empty))).
tree2(node(~, node(+, empty, node(*, empty, empty)), node(!, node(/,empty, empty),empty))).
badTree( node(3, node(5, empty), empty)) .

?- tree2(T), memberT(!,T).
T = node(~, node(+, empty, node(*, empty, empty)), node(!, node(/, empty, empty), empty)) .
?- tree1(T),memberT(100,T).
T = node(10, empty, node(100, empty, empty)) .
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this was exactly your question but here is the code to produce the results you give (assuming they are meant to be a specification):

```
memberT(Val, node( Val,  _Left, _Right)).
memberT(Val, node(_Val1,  Left, _Right)) :- memberT(Val, Left).
memberT(Val, node(_Val1, _Left,  Right)) :- memberT(Val, Right).
```